# Trying to extend jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-hover

I'm extending jQuery with a function I wrote called bindHoverEvents:

```
$.fn.bindHoverEvents = function () {
    this.hover ( function () {
            // mouseenter function
        }, function () {
            // mouseleave function
        }
     );
};
```

The problem is that when I call this function on an object, the hover events are not bound to it:

```
$(object).bindHoverEvents();
```

I know bindHoverEvents is getting called, because when I put an alert at the beginning of the function, right before this.hover(...), the alert shows up. However, when I put the same alert inside of the mouseenter function, it doesn't show up when I hover over the object. Any ideas why?

Comment: Your code works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/SYNrz/

Comment: Are you passing function references to your jQuery method? Also, the name is flawed. Events are not bound, they trigger - event *handlers* are bound.

Comment: Thank you Šime Vidas for the correction on the name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. When I called $(object).bindHoverEvents(), object was just an instance of a javascript object, not an element in the DOM.

Woops...